# Practical use for negative $dt.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, physics, mathematical-physics

I am writing a section of notes for Calculus 1 on related rates.  In the section where I discuss differentials, I write that the quantity $dt$ must be nonnegative.  I imagined the only reason it would be negative is in theoretical time travel, or in the extrapolation of what might have happened prior to a known event.  SO here's my question:

When is it practical, or even possible, to utilize a negative value for $dt?$

Comment: If "dt" is just a subset of a typographical painting, as in ${dy\over dt}$, it doesn't make sense to ask whether it is positive or negative. But as soon as $dt$ is a variable or function related in a particular way to the "primary" variable or function $t$ there is no reason to stipulate $dt>0$ as a general law.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, I once again ask how does one "stipulate dt<0 as a general law" in a practical sense?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how you organize your problem.
Suppose your problem takes place in a time interval $a \le t \le b$.  Some things you know are $f'(t)$ and $f(b)$.  Then to find $f(t)$, you may think of integrating backward from $b$.  And maybe some ways to write that would involve thinking of negative $dt$.

Comment: I think this is in line with "extrapolation of what might have happened prior to a known event."  Just in this case, we might not be extrapolating if we have a known behavior for the entire interval of $t$ given.

Comment: Classical mechanics is entirely reversible. Basically it predicts classical mechanics precisely in both time directions. As I said it's not until you hit heat and dissipation of energy in essentially stochastic ways that you begin to lose that exact reversibility. For example if you know a planet's exact displacement or location, and its exact velocity vector using Newtonian gravitation you can exactly describe it's position at any time after as well as any time before. Also is interesting, it is arbitrary to say $t=0$ as the starting point. But this is just shifting not reflecting $t$ about 0

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to classical physics, yes? It seems that you have 3 degrees of freedom or coordinates and basis. The displacement vectors or velocity or what ever contravariant vector you have exists independent of the coordinates and can change it's inherent position. This change is most often seen as continuous and t is nothing more than a parameterization the objects path inside 3 dimensions. So $-t$ makes sense classically. Very generally the object may exist in $\Bbb R^3$ so considering time independent relations (like gradient which is only concerned with the spatial quantities) you can describe some situation sometimes with only respect to the 3 spatial cooridnates.

You can consider interaction $f:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ the intuitive motion of the some body or transformation of it's position would typically be continous and is clearly only a function of it's coordinates current location.

But you can consider $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^3$ and then consider $f \circ g :\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^3$. Also it does make sense in classical mechanics to consider $-\frac{d}{dt}x$ and you do it all the time in classical mechanics. I think the notions of negative time or time differential only start to break down in systems were thermodynamics effects are taken into account due to unrecoverable losses of energy which make it extremely difficult to predict the reverse reactions. But mathematically in typical calculus I think it is certainly well defined and meaningful, and in classical mechanics as well.

Comment: So how would one explain $x$ is a decreasing quantity when $dx$ is positive?

Comment: Hmm it is difficult because we are speaking about x coordinate and t. When we negate t we need an underlying coordinate system with which it was negated to. Let's consider $t_0$ which is a fixed t coordinate system that will not change. Then say $\frac{d}{dt_0}x >0$. If $t=-t_0$ then $\frac{d}{dt}x<0$. Your wording is not easy cause $dx$ is positive so we would expect that if time were flowing backwards or the motion "undoing itself" or $dt$ negative, then $x$ should be decreasing, no?

Comment: I need to focus on something practical here.  I am writing to a group of high school students.  See the examples I gave in the OP.

Comment: In that case I think it may not be likely that they will find advantage in considering negative time rates. And best to just assume cases were $dt > 0$ maybe discuss it a little. But I think lay down an underlying coordinate system for t, then consider 2 different t's both the negation of the other and say that they can have though experiemet on what it would be like for time to flow backwards.